# RestAssured- object in body throws Error

Tags: java, rest-assured

My Object which i pass in test

```
@Data
public class UserRequest {
@JsonProperty("name")
private final String name;
@JsonProperty("surname")
private final String surname;
@JsonProperty("email")
private final String email;
@JsonProperty("iaAdmin")
private final boolean isAdmin;
```

}

than i have it test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class UserControllerIT {

@LocalServerPort
private int port;

@Test
public void testIsCreatingNewUser() throws IOException{
    given()
            .when()
            .body(new UserRequest("asd","sad","asd",false))//.body(TestGenerator.getUserRequest())
            .port(port)
            .post("/user/" + TestGenerator.randomUUID)
            .then()
            .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_CREATED);
}
```

i got error:

`java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: Provider com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinModule could not be instantiated`

and at the bottom stack

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 79 more
```

What is going on?! Kotlin...i use java with spring boot v2.0 m3

Comment: What IDE are you using? Sometimes there are errors with downloaded dependencies (incomplete downloads, broken files.. etc) Try deleting the .m2/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/kotlin folder and try refreshing the project to download all dependencies again.

Comment: It seems like a part of your environment uses kotlin, which is a language that can be put on top of a JVM to extend the language. Do you have Android studio, for example? You could probably track down which component you are using is relying on Kotlin.

Comment: Intellij IDEA 2017.2, i have android studio bur i didnt use for a long time. i will try remove .m2

Comment: Removing .m2 and download sources again didnt work, maybe it is spring boot v2 fault

Comment: Ok. It should be included but try adding kotlin dependency to pom.xml:

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3-2</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Thank you, i found solution thanks to your hint. It needs kotlin dependencies...but i dont know why, strange Spring Boot v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer question myself. Thank to @Sebastian Duque comment i add dependencies from 
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-kotlin
and it helped...

```
<!--kotlin/ it needs jackson to map objects-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jre8</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

but it is strange that Jackson in Spring Boot v2 needs Kotlin dependendecies... I use jackson dependencies from spring-boot starters so i didnt include any jackson.

Answer (score 0):

If you use maven exclude  from spring-boot dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.M6</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
 </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.M6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

For other build tools, update this solution